# Is this empty loop executing infinitely?

Tags: c++

I have this code right here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int counter = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  while(counter < 10);
  {
    sum += ++ counter;
  }
  cout << sum << endl;
}
```

I was wondering if the line `while(counter < 10);` is an infinite loop which results in the rest of the code not being executed.

Another side question, since the while is delimited with `;`, that block of code under it is just an inner scope of code?

Comment: The code wont continue beyond `while`. Also I dont think you can call the code inside `{ }` inner scope since if you comment out the `while` the code inside `{ }` will run by itself. In this case commenting out `while(counter < 10);` will give you a sum of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as the initial value of `counter` is `0` then the statement

```
while (counter < 10);
```

which is implicitly

```
while (counter < 10) {}
```

is an infinite loop.  And yes, due to the terminating semi-colon on the while statement, the subsequent braced block is just another scope.

Answer (score 1):

The code `while(counter < 10);` causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) due to not making forward progress on a thread.

In practice this might mean that execution hangs, or execution skips over that line, or anything else. The compiler might optimize the whole program to output `1`, or `11`.

For further reading see [Forward progress - progress guarantee](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Forward_progress)

Comment: Is the reason for it's discontinuity because the loop is executing but never able to evaluate the conditional as false?

Comment: @Blanker You could look at the assembly output generated by your compiler to get a hint of what is happening on your system.

Comment: I have this to look at: https://godbolt.org/g/Gjg8Kz but I personally don't know what any of the assembly means, except that maybe since it has no `ret` command (again, very little knowledge of asm) I assume the `jmp` means it keeps looping.

Comment: @Blanker yes, `jmp .LBB0_1` means that execution jumps to the label `.LBBO_1:`